# performing virtual alignment between ontologically annotated JSON objects

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, semantic-web, ontology

I have an application that requests JSON objects from various other applications via their REST APIs. The response from any application comes in the following format:

```
{
data : {
        key1: { val: value, defBy: "ontology class"}
        key2: ...,
     }
}
```

The following code depicts an object from App1:

```
{
data : {
        key1: { val: "98404506-385576361", defBy: "abc:SHA-224"}
     }
}
```

The following code depicts an object from App2:

```
{
    data : {
            key2: { val: "495967838-485694812", defBy: "xyz:SHA3-224"}
         }
    }
```

Here, `DefBy` refers to the algorithm used to encrypt the string in `val`. When my application receives such objects, it parses the JSON and converts each kv in the object into RDF such that:

```
// For objects from App1:
key1 rdf:type osba:key
key1 osba:generatedBy abc:SHA-224
...
// For objects from App2
key2 rdf:type osba:key
key2 osba:generatedBy xyz:SHA3-224
```

I need to query the generated RDF data in a way that I can specify *if `osba:generatedBy` of any key belongs to the SHA family, then return the subject as a valid query-result,* such that: `where {?k osba:generatedBy ???}`

Please note the following points:

1. I also receive objects with other encryption algorithms such as `MD5`, etc.
2. I don't know in advance what encryption algorithm will be used by a new application joining the network nor what `NS` it uses. For example, in the above objects, one uses `abc:`, and the other uses `xyz:`.
3. I can't use SPARQL filtering because the value could be `SecureHashAlgorithm` instead of `SHA`

My problem is that I can't define an upper (referenced) ontology in advance and map the value stored in `defBy:` of the incoming objects, because I don't know in advance what ontology is used nor what encryption algorithm the value represents.

I read about Automatic Ontology Integration, Alignment, Mapping, etc,. but I can't find the rationale of this concept to my problem.

Any solutions?

Comment: Can you elaborate point 3? Which filters did you try that didn't work?

Comment: I tried to use wild card function like Sha* but I can't solve the problem because of the reason expressed in P-3

Comment: Without an integrating ontology, you can't do query expansion or the like. Obviously, you need a mapping of synonym terms, otherwise, you can't write a complete and correct filter. And that holds for every domain.

Comment: The point with the namespaces is also not clear. They are just syntactic sugar and do not contribute to the semantics of a SPARQL query.

Answer (score 0):

> 3) I can't use SPARQL filtering because the value could be `SecureHashAlgorithm` instead of `SHA`

SPARQL filtering [supports matching against regular expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-regex) as defined by [xpath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax). Thus, something along the line of

```
SELECT ?key
 WHERE { ?key osba:generatedBy  ?generator
         FILTER regex(?generator, "^s(ecure)?h(ash)?a(lgorithm)?.*", "i") }
```

(*note: untested*) should do the job. To build a good regex I can recommend http://regexr.com/

In case it's necessary: You can convert an IRI to a string (for matching) with [the `str()` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-str).

Comment: I need to uses semantics not regular expressions, since strings can change what if the incoming type is   FIPS PUB 180-4 ? the certification code for SHA3

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you put together a small example with input data and expected output? If it's only about SHA being referenced by "fips pub 180-4" then just include that into your regex?